# how to use NotifyDataSetChange in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I'm new to c# and xamarin, my sort works but the data in my Listview doesn't seems to be affected. I've tried using NotifyDataSetChange but it seems like I'm not using it correcty.

my code:

```
  public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            List<Mountain> filteredMountains;

            int id = item.ItemId;
            if (id == Resource.Id.srtAtoZ)
            {
                filteredMountains = (mMountains.OrderBy(mountain => mountain.MtName)).ToList();
                mAdapter = new MountainsAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ml_model, filteredMountains);
                mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();                
                mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;

            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.srtZtoA)
            {
                filteredMountains = (mMountains.OrderByDescending(mountain => mountain.MtName).ToList());
                mAdapter = new MountainsAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ml_model, filteredMountains);
                mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();                
                mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;
            }
      else if (id == Resource.Id.srtMaslAsc)
            {
                filteredMountains = (mMountains.OrderBy(mountain => mountain.Masl)).ToList();
                mAdapter = new MountainsAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ml_model, filteredMountains);
                mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;
            }
                 else if (id == Resource.Id.srtMaslDesc)
            {
                filteredMountains = (mMountains.OrderByDescending(mountain => mountain.Masl)).ToList();
                mAdapter = new MountainsAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ml_model, filteredMountains);
                mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;
            }
```

EDITED..

my update method in my adapter

```
public  void Update(List<Mountain> mLists)
      {
          mtList.Clear();
          NotifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

how I call my adapter..

```
    else if (id == Resource.Id.action2)
        {
            List<Mountain> filteredMountains = (mMountains.OrderByDescending(mountain => mountain.MtName).ToList());

            mAdapter.Update(filteredMountains);
            RunOnUiThread(() => mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
```

Comment: Since you are already implementing a custom Adapter, why not just have a property and keep the same Adapter around for the entire life of this view? Then just swap out the ItemsSource and call NotifyDataSetChanged() on the Adapter. No need to create new instances all the time. Also you are calling NotifyDataSetChanged before you are setting the adapter on your ListView.

Comment: hello sir cheesebaron! As I've red in your comments in xamarin forums. I've created an Update method in my Adapter. I edited my question and added what my codes looks like right now.. still doesn't work :(

Comment: You don't add your new filtered Mountains after you clear them in your Update method.

Comment: then what should i put there? am I missing something in my update method? as I kept researching I saw in java , after they clear the list they put addAll() then notifydatasetchange. tried it but im getting error.

Comment: mtList.AddRange(mLists) right after clear

Comment: after adding addrange on my update method.. can I add my filteredmountains as a parameter now? thank you for your answers sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you sir cheesebaron..

adding this method on my adapter solved my problem :)

```
public  void Update(List<Mountain> mLists)
    {
        mtList.Clear();
        mtList.AddRange(mLists);
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and used this to call my adapter

```
mAdapter.Update(filteredMountains);
RunOnUiThread(() => mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
```

Comment: The second call to `NotifyDataSetChanged()` is not needed. You call it twice this way.